# How do you model a typical friend-to-friend relationship in a relational database?

Tags: sql, data-modeling

What is the appropriate way of modeling a friend-to-friend relationship in a relational database? I'll detail out what I mean by a friend-to-friend relationship below.

**friend-to-friend relationship**

Assuming we have a table with persons. These persons can be friends with each other. Being a friend means that a person and another person are connected through a relationship that only includes those two persons.

**My best, not satisfactory, idea so far**

- A table containing persons
- A table containing the relationships
- A table containing the many-to-many-relationship between persons and
  relationships

As in the image below.

[proposed data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lar1X.png)

This seems fine from a data-modeling perspective, but when writing a SQL query that would check whether two given person_ids are friends or not, the query becomes rather complex, which makes me think this is not the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: I will do it with only two tables: persons and relationship. If each person have an ID, the relationship table will contain the two IDs of the friends. If you want to manage the one way friendship (i.e. I follow you and you don't follow me), you can create 2 rows with inverted IDs if the relation is bidirectional. This will also simplify the query

Comment: I am interpreting it correctly when I say that the relationship table would then have two columns, both containing person_id? Assuming this is the case, the thing I don't like about this solution is that you would need to check whether the persons are in either column, because it is arbitrary which person that goes into each. The problem of this becomes even more clear if you generalize and say that you want to model relationships of dynamic sizes, e.g. instead of a friend-to-friend relationship you have groups or teams containing certain people. Then this solution does not work. Right?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend a table with two person_id-columns and maybe a relationshiptype-id for different relationships

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [Friend - Friend - Relationship] link table.

```
[Friend]---[Link_table]---[Relationship]
                 |
              [Friend]
```

:)
**EDIT:**

Where for example [Table]: columns...

- [Friend]: PK_Friend, Name, LastName
- [Link]: PK_Link, PK_Friend1, PK_Friend2, PK_RelationShip
- [RelationShip]: PK_RelationShip, RelationShipDescription

Comment: Can you elaborate on the columns in the link_table and the relationship table?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table individuals (
  individual_id int primary key,
  full_name varchar(255)
);

create table relationships (
  from_individual_id int references individuals(individual_id),
  type varchar(255) check (type in ('FRIEND OF')), -- should be a lookup table
  to_individual_id int references individuals(individual_id),

  primary key (from_individual_id, to_individual_id, type),
  check (from_individual_id <> to_individual_id)
);
```

I can think that you are my friend, but you don't think I am your friend...

But generally "from" thinks "to" is a friend and vice-versa, so you'll to add the reverse relationship as another row

Comment: Thanks for your informative and concrete proposal of code for the problem, Neil. Though, it is not exactly what I am trying to achieve, though it could be me not being specific enough in my question.

The relationship between the two individuals should not go in any direction. Either they are friends or they are not.